# Is it safe to pass nullptr to C function?

Tags: c++, c, clion

I have some library written in pure C. Now I'm creating some unit tests but the testing library is written in C++ rather than C. When I pass NULL to API function under test CLion gives me a hint to pass nullptr instead of NULL. Is it safe to pass nullptr to pure C function in this case?

Comment: Should be safe. `nullptr` is implicitly convertible to null pointer of any type, so with `extern "C" f(int*)`, calling `f(nullptr)` is equivalent to `f((int*)0)`, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it safe to pass nullptr to pure C function in this case?

I think it is. From [the C++11 standard (4.10 Pointer conversions)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.ptr):

> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression ([expr.const]) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A *null pointer constant* can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type.

A `nullptr` and an intergral constant expression that evaluates to `0` are equivalent for such conversions.